# How to find a PDF for which $f(x) = |x| - x^2$ is $0$ in the limit?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, limits

I have two functions of $x$: $f(x) = |x|$ and $g(x) = x^2$. Now I want to find a PDF for which when I draw random samples from their value approaches zero in the as I draw an infinite number of samples. From my understanding, this relates to me finding a PDF for the following joint function:
[$\sqrt{x^2} - x^2$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTtwe.png)

I tried to simplify the problem with the following, but was unable to generalise it to my scenario: Let $h(x) = x$. Then it follows that any symmetric PDF with mean zero will adhere to this property.

Could anyone provide me with not only the specific solution but also indicate to me how to solve such a problem generally?

Edit: Some context: I am trying to find a distribution of errors of a model fitted to data for which the mean squared error and mean absolute error are identical.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you, I am sorry this is a typo i fixed it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want $E(x) = 0$ and $E(|x|) = E(x^2)$?

Comment: @ronno yes exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponential distribution $p(x)=e^{-2|x|}$ is an example:
\begin{align}
E(|x|)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|e^{-2|x|}dx = \frac{1}{2}
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-2|x|}dx = E(x^2).
\end{align}

---

Another example is the normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma)$ with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$:
$$
E(|x|)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|e^{-\pi x^2/4}=\frac{2}{\pi} =\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\pi x^2/4}=E(x^2).
$$

---

(Almost) general method of solution: choose an even probability distribution function (so that $E(x)=0$) dependent on one or more parameters $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, compute $E(|x|)$ and $E(x^2)$ (which will be functions of those parameters), and solve the equation $E(|x|)=E(x^2)$.

Comment: thank you for both the examples and attempt at a general method of solving this!

Comment: correct me if i am mistaken, but must a PDF not integrate to 1? As such, your solution is almost correct and simply needs to be multiplied by 2.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. I understand they both integrate to 1/2 and 2/π respectively and not to 1 right? So, I would need to multiply the first one by 2 and the second one by 1/2π. Please let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Ah now I see my mistake thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A uniform distribution on $[-3/2, 3/2]$ seems to satisfy what you want:
$$E(|x|) = 2\int_0^{3/2} \tfrac13 x \, dx = \frac{3}{4} = 2\int_0^{3/2} \tfrac13 x^2 \, dx = E(x^2)\,.$$

As to how I found it, I just restricted the search to uniform distributions that are symmetric around $0$, which are determined by the width of the support. For very narrow supports, the mean of $|x|$ is higher since near $0$, $|x| > x^2$. Similarly for very wide supports the mean of $x^2$ is higher, since that dominates for large $x$. So by continuity something in between needs to work, and it's just a matter of solving the equation.

Comment: thank you for your efforts and example!